# Casting to ctypes.wintypes

Tags: python, ctypes

My code:

```
coord = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(console_handle)
```

`coord`'s real type is `ctypes.wintypes._COORD` but when I access it, it is an `int`.

How can I cast `coord` to `ctyles.wintypes._COORD`?

I’ve already tried `ctyles.wintypes._COORD(coord)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this mailing list post](http://osdir.com/ml/python.ctypes/2005-12/msg00029.html), you can set the `restype` attribute of the `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize` function. This seems to work on my setup, though I'm not sure what other implications it might have. The linked post implies that struct return values are not officially supported, so use with care.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> import ctypes.wintypes
>>> 
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize.restype = ctypes.wintypes._COORD
>>> coord = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11))
>>> print(type(coord))
<class 'ctypes.wintypes._COORD'>
>>> print(coord.X, coord.Y)
160 81
```

Comment: Works perfect. Just curious but how did you find the mailing list post? Did you see it before? It's better than struct unpacking and packing.

Comment: @Zuck I had it archived from some long-forgotten project. It was a nice bonus that the question was almost exactly the same, though :-D

Comment: That is what surprised me. :)

Comment: @Zuck I expect the ugliness of manually extracting both values from a single int makes the `COORD` type a popular target for this sort of hackery.